# Using Ajax on Home controller and view to call partial view from a different controllers

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Im working on an ASP.NET MVC project in which i would like to use the @Ajax.ActionLink to call partial views from separate controllers.

Ive figured out how to call a partial view on the same controller using:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Load Forms", "Index", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "divForms", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace })
```

How can i ammend this to call a function on a completely different controller?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Load Forms", "Index", "ControllerName", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "divForms", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace })
```

Note the 3rd parameter being the name of the controller. See MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505194(v=vs.118).aspx